# Can't access running EC2 Dockerized image from outside

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

#### The problem

I can't access a running docker image from outside of the EC2 instance.

#### What I've tried

- I created a cluster in ECS, a service with a related task definition and an Application Load Balancer.
- When the task gets executed I can see the logs from the Docker image in the task:
  [image]
- I also see the related EC2 instance running. When I ssh into the instance I can see the docker image running, as expected:

```
docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                                COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                 PORTS                     NAMES
af20230498fb        <ecr-id>.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/app-be:latest   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   11 minutes ago      Up 11 minutes          0.0.0.0:32805->5001/tcp   ecs-app-task-definition-26-app-be-fcf9ffc3f9dadf80d401
5d59c2b2bcaa        amazon/amazon-ecs-agent:latest                                       "/agent"                 2 hours ago         Up 2 hours (healthy)                             ecs-agent
```

And when I do:

```
> curl 0.0.0.0:32805/status
{"message":"OK","timestamp":1598871064086}
```

- Also my load balancer seems to be set up correctly:
  [image]

But when trying to access the same endpoint from outside, both from the public IP of the EC2 instance and the Application Load Balancer DNS, it times out.

**Also**: the health checks for /status of the Application Load Balancer are failing as well, so the tasks restarts every 15 minutes.

Any help is appreciated, and sorry in advance if I'm making a rookie mistake, as I don't have much experience with AWS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you config your Security Group of your EC2 or the NACL of the VPC where the EC2 is launched?

I see that you are expose port 5001 in your task so in the SG, you should open that port

Comment: Thank you for that, the SG wasn't allowing any TCP incoming requests.

Comment: You're welcome. Please tell me if my advice help you :D

Comment: Yes it did, I modified the security group of both the EC2 instances and the Application Load balancer and is now working as expected!